# ref and byref<> parameters in F# class members

Tags: f#

I rewrote some my f# functions definitions to static members and stuck at ref/byref parameter error:

```
static member bar (a : byref<int>) = Foo.bar &a 

Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'int ref'    
but here has type
    'byref<'a>'
```

Are there some differences with byref parameters between 'let' and static definitions?

UPD:

It's worked example of what I have changed to static member definition:

```
> let rec foo (a :byref<int>) = 
    a <- a-1
    if a > 0 then
        System.Console.Write(a.ToString()); foo &a
    else a
;;
val foo : a:byref<int> -> int

> let mutable a = 3;; 
val mutable a : int = 3

> foo &a;;
21val it : int = 0
```

Now it looks like that and it doesn't work. Why? :

```
> type Foo() =
    static member bar (a : byref<int>) = 
        a <- a-1
        if a > 0 then
            System.Console.Write(a.ToString()); foo &a
        else a;;
type Foo =
  class
    new : unit -> Foo
    static member bar : a:byref<int> -> int
  end   

> let mutable b = 3;;
val mutable b : int = 3

> Foo.bar &b;;

  Foo.bar &b;;
  --------^^

stdin(71,9): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'int ref'    
but here has type
    'byref<'a>'
```

Comment: It's not possible to say what's wrong without seeing minimal reproducible example. Can you share other parts of the code, especially the definition of `Foo.bar`?

Comment: @TomasPetricek sorry, I thinked that it is clear. I've added additional information to question

Comment: @KovalevRoman I've copied your code to fsi and it works as expected. Make sure that you haven't overriden the definition in your F# interactive session.

Comment: @TomasPetricek definitely not, it is default F# Interactive version 4.1 in VS 2017

Answer (score 3):

`int ref` is type definition of F# [Reference Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells), while `byref<'a>` is an equivalent of C# `ref`/`out` arguments (an argument passed by reference even when it's a value type).

While it's impossible to tell anything more without reproducible snippet, it's quite possible that you've conflated two types:

```fs
let myFunc(a: int ref) = a := 1

// this is wrong
let a = 1
myFunc &a

// this is right
let a = ref 1
myFunc a
```

Comment: sorry, I thinked that it is clear. I've added additional information to question